# how to display all the mondays when you select monday in a calendar using Calendar control asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DateTime dtime1 = new DateTime();
    dtime1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

    DateTime dtime = new DateTime();
    dtime = dtime1.AddDays(7);
    Response.Write(dtime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</br>");
}
```

I need to display all the Mondays when i select Monday of the current month. Should i use bool? I have to code using loop concepts.

Comment: until the end of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dtime1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate;         

int iTotalDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtime1.Year, dtime1.Month) - dtime1.Day;

for (int i = 1; i <= iTotalDays; i++)
{
  var d = dtime1.AddDays(i);
  if (d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) 
       Response.Write(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</br>");
}
```

**UPDATE**:

All mondays of current month:

```
DateTime dtime1 = DateTime.Now;       

int iTotalDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtime1.Year, dtime1.Month);

for (int i = 1; i <= iTotalDays; i++)
{
    var d = new DateTime(dtime1.Year, dtime1.Month, i);
    if (d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)          
        Response.Write(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</br>");
}
```

Comment: My answer is almost similar to yours. :-). Although, yours is much simpler. Upvoted.

Comment: but my question is to display all the dates of mondays of the current month when i select monday ..

Comment: Means if you select monday in the calendar. You want to show print all mondays of current month? selected month can be different from current month?

Comment: I have to print all mondays of current month only.

Comment: Hi Hassan.. I need to use loop to check whether it is Monday or not in the same program instead of DayOfWeek.Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should help you in displaying all the Mondays of a particular month.

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    DateTime dtime1 = new DateTime();
    dtime1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    // get a list of all dates
    var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtime1.Year, dtime1.Month)).Select(n => new DateTime(dtime1.Year, dtime1.Month, n));
    // then filter mondays like following
    var mondays = from d in dates
                   where d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
                   select d;
    List<DateTime> listOfMondays = mondays.ToList();
    // then you can loop through the listOfMondays and write it on the response.

}
```